# actionscript 3 flash removing a child - bring it back?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i just started learning flash. Anyways, I have a movieclip that is removed when i quit the game from the menu e.g. `removeChild(character)`. When i press "start" on the menu, i would like the character to re-appear. How can i add him again ONLY if he's been deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use addChild again to add him. To test if he is added/deleted, you can test if his stage property is true.

```
if (!character.stage) 
{
    addChild(character);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution. Should it be if (!character.stage) addChild(character)? If the child has been removed, wouldn't the stage property be null? Also, wouldn't this solution only work if the parent clip is on the display list (i.e. it would be useless for reattaching a child to a parent that had also been removed from the display list). I've always used the DisplayObjectContainer.contains() function for this kind of tests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to change the visibility of the child or temporarily exclude it from the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent property of the character to see if it is attached to anything. Note however that it is perfectly fine to use addChild on a display object that is already added.

Comment: reusing addChild on something that is already added will bring it to the top of the display list :)

Comment: That is true. I just meant using addChild on an already added object won't cause an error. I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

when removing save it in a var

```
var mySavedCharacter:MovieClip = characater
removeChild(character)
```

When adding it back just add the saved var

```
addChild(mySavedCharacter)
```

Also remember objects are passed by reference so a change to character will also change mySavedCharacter.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure that you have a reference to the MovieClip you want to re-add to the stage. If you are creating this MovieClip in a function and not saving off a reference, you will have to do a "dirty" look-up to get a reference. Here is an example of how to create a reference for later use:

```
var myMovieClip : MovieClip; // make sure you have this outside of a function

function createMyMovieClip() : void
{
    myMovieClip = new MovieClip();
    addMyMovieClip();
}
```

Now that you have that reference to the MovieClip you can do something like this:

```
function addMyMovieClip() : void
{
    stage.addChild( myMovieClip );
}

function removeMyMovieClip : void
{
    stage.removeChild( myMovieClip );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!yourContainer.contains(character)) yourContainer.addChild(character);
```

This code assumes "yourContainer" is a valid DisplayObjectContainer reference, and that "character" is a non-null reference to a DisplayObject.

Also, make sure that you're saving a reference to your character MovieClip/Sprite other than just adding to the display list, so that it is not GC'd.